# Win Server 2008 R2 - Mapped shared folder hanging?

Tags: mappeddrive

I have recently built a windows 2008 server R2 machine. This is purely for file server purposes and is very much a basic build.

All windows updates installed and part of domain.

I have setup a shared folder on the C:Drive and added permissions for domain users as co-owners.

The client machines run XP SP3 and are part of the domain also. We have a few servers running the same setups on a few of our sites but this one is particular crashes users machines (explorer.exe hangs for at least a few mins) when attempting to access the shared folder.

I have turned off the option on the network card for power save aswell still no change.

Comment: Are you connecting to the shared folder with a hostname or IP?

Answer (score 0):

It really could just be a faulty disk problem.  I had a new server that kept hanging during any sizable file transfer and tried everything from switches and routers to windows updates, and it turned out simply to be a faulty, albeit brand new, hard drive was causing the malfunction.  I would say that this seems even more likely in this scenario because you've had success with this configuration on other machines.  The solution is simple really, replace the hard drive.

One little word though, if C: is also the windows system drive, it's best practice to put your shared folder on another drive.  It may be worth partitioning your root drive into C: and D: in order to keep your shared folders and windows system separate.  The reason for doing this comes down to security, it's apparently easier for someone to do damage to your sys internals if they came in via shared folder access on your root drive letter.